# Making a game in JavaFX8. How can I switch from Splash page to Cutscene to Level?

Tags: java, javafx

this is my first game using JavaFX so I admittedly have made some bad design decisions, probably.

Anyway, I want to transition from a splash page (Splash class) to a cutscene (Cutscene class) and then to a playable level (PlayableLevel class). The game is launched from my Main class and transitions are supposed to be done with keyboard inputs (Enter button).

The method in Main that starts the game looks like this:

```
public void start (Stage s) {
        // create your own game here
        Splash splashPage = new Splash();
        Cutscene cs = new Cutscene();
        PlayableLevel play = new PlayableLevel();
        // attach game to the stage and display it
        Scene scene0 = splashPage.init(SIZE, SIZE);
        Scene scene1 = cs.init(SIZE, SIZE, 0);
        Scene scene2 = play.init(SIZE, SIZE, 0);
        s.setScene(scene0);
        s.show();

        // sets the game's loop
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(MILLISECOND_DELAY),
                                      e -> myGame.step(SECOND_DELAY));
        Timeline animation = new Timeline();
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        animation.play();
    }
```

My question in particular is what should I do to make it so that the Splash class can communicate with the Main class so that once a keystroke event is recorded, the stage can set a new scene? I'm currently reading about EventHandlers but I'm unsure of the exact implementation as of now.

EDIT: One idea I had was to make a linked list of Scenes, and then once some event happens (keystroke), then I would set the scene to the next one in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Splash {

    private Runnable nextSceneHandler ;

    public void setNextSceneHandler(Runnable handler) {
        nextSceneHandler = handler ;
    }

    public Scene init(double width, double height) {
        Scene scene = new Scene();

        // Just an example handler, you could do the same for
        // button events, menus, etc., or even just handlers for the
        // end of an animation 
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (nextSceneHandler != null) {
                if (e.getCode() == ...) {
                    nextSceneHandler.run();
                }
            }
        }
        // existing code...
    }

    // existing code ...
}
```

and similarly for `CutScene`.

Then

```
public void start (Stage s) {
    // create your own game here
    Splash splashPage = new Splash();
    Cutscene cs = new Cutscene();
    PlayableLevel play = new PlayableLevel();

    // attach game to the stage and display it
    Scene scene0 = splashPage.init(SIZE, SIZE);
    Scene scene1 = cs.init(SIZE, SIZE, 0);
    Scene scene2 = play.init(SIZE, SIZE, 0);

    splashPage.setNextSceneHandler(() -> s.setScene(scene1));
    cs.setNextSceneHandler(() -> s.setScene(scene2));

    s.setScene(scene0);
    s.show();

    // sets the game's loop
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(MILLISECOND_DELAY),
                                  e -> myGame.step(SECOND_DELAY));
    Timeline animation = new Timeline();
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
    animation.play();
}
```

Your linked list idea should work too. You need a mechanism for passing the linked list instance (or perhaps an iterator from it) to each of the scene generating classes; their event handlers would execute code like

```
scene.getWindow().setScene(sceneIterator.next());
```

I kind of prefer setting the runnable on the objects, as it feels a little more flexible. Just a question of style though.